# Защита приложения c#

Tags: c#, wcf

Приложение парсер и база данных.
Используемая база данных - sqlliteсrypt, она открывается только по ключу.
Необходимо, чтобы полная функциональность парсинга (ручное или автоматическое разгадывание капчи например) и экспорт данных из базы данных были только на время выданного ключа к программе, который проверяется отправляя запрос на сервер.
Вопросы:

1. как защитить базу данных - в программе же есть код, который подключает базу данных и там присутствует секретный ключ криптования - поможет ли в данном случаем обфускация .Net Reactor?
2. Что лучше вынести на сервер, чтобы нивелировать возможности дизассемблирования?

Comment: если хотите защитить код - унесите его на сервер и сделайте тонкий клиент.

Comment: какой код в данном случае можно вынести на сервер?если процесс парсинга и хранение данных должно быть на компе пользователя

Comment: @АрхиповВладимир Все что вы хотите защитить. Все что на машине пользователя - может быть потенциально взломано.

Comment: Базу данных, находяющуюся у клиента не защитить, даже в 1С пытались, но даже близко не смогли. Чтобы реально защитить данные, они должны быть у вас под контролем - не сервере. И сервер должен контроллировать доступ к этим данным. Унесите на сервер весь "интересный" код и не придется мучаться с обфускаторами, которые кстати в итоге бесполезны, они увеличивают сложность добычи вашего кода, но не защищают полностью.